# Exception Firebase Auth on flutter, using vccode

Tags: dart, flutter

I am developing a login system, using firebase, flutter and vscode.

I would like to know how to handle exceptions generated by Firebase.
If EMAIL is already registered.

Currently generating an error:

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, The email address is already in use by another account., null))
```

If the email is already registered, I want to inform the user.

CODE:

```
Future<void> signUp({@required Map<String, dynamic> userData,@required String pass,@required VoidCallback onSuccess,@required VoidCallback onFail}) async{
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: userData["email"],
      password: pass
    ).then((user) async{
      firebaseUser = user;
      await _saveUserData(userData);
      onSuccess();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }).catchError((e){

      print(e);
      onFail();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });

  }
```

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform subsequent operations when ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE is emitted.

I think it's a good idea to catch a PlatformException and branch the process with `code` as shown below.

```
try {
  final result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
  );
} on PlatformException catch (exception) {
  switch (exception.code) {
  case 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE':
    // do something...
  default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `on PlatformException catch (e)` and if `(e.message == 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE')` to handle this case.